# Run python file in subdirectory Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I have the following file structure

```
project 
├── app
│   ├── main.py
│   └── combine.py
│   └── scrape.py
├── resources
|    └── secrets.py
|    └── config.py
|    └── requirements.txt
|--- Dockerfile
```

My Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN mkdir /project
WORKDIR /project

COPY ./resources/requirements.txt ./
ADD ./resources/. /resources/
ADD ./app/. /app/

RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "./app/main.py" ]
```

I build my image using `docker build -t my-app .` and run using `docker run my-app`

I get the following error
`python: can't open file './app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Can I keep subdirectory file structure and successfully run a Docker image? All the tutorials/ questions I have seen previously have the Dockerfile in the same directory as all the code that it depends on - is this a requirement? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your WORKDIR is set to /project.

Your CMD is run as './app', so that translates to '/project/app'.

You're copying app to '/app', so use this:

`CMD [ "python", "/app/main.py" ]`

Comment: Thanks! Now getting import errors that I can't get my head around but that might have to be a new question

Comment: You can use relative paths for the destination argument of `COPY` and `ADD`, so `COPY ./resources/ ./resources/` and keeping your current directory layout will address this too.